# Is it possible to get an S3 file url before it's uploaded?

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

So, here's the scenario. I have a site which allows you to perform certain operations on files, *which take on the order of seconds*. I don't want the client to have to wait that long before the server returns a response so they way we have it now is that

1. User performs an operation in their browser (client)
2. Client sends a POST request to server with parameters
3. Server adds operation to job queue and sends back **the expected url of the result**
4. Client pings server until file is available then serves it

Currently these files are being stored in my ec2 server but I want to move this to S3. I was wondering if this type of flow is possible.

The server knows what the file will be saved and to where way before it actually is, so is that the same case with S3? Is there a way of knowing the file URL if I know all the information beforehand (bucket, filename, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All S3 object URLs follow patterns, so it's easy to know what the URL *will* be ahead of time.

If the bucket name is DNS-compliant (required of all regions except for US Standard), then it'll look like this:

```
<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object-path>
```

The U.S. Standard region is a bit more lax in it's bucket name rules (they aren't *required* to be DNS-compliant), so some may look like this:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object-path>
```

So, if your bucket name is something DNS-compliant (e.g., `example`), and your file is `abc/123/file.txt`, then your object URL will be:

```
example.s3.amazonaws.com/abc/123/file.txt
```

So, if your bucket name is NOT DNS-compliant (e.g., `EXAMPLE_123`), and your file is `abc/123/file.txt`, then your object URL will be:

```
s3.amazonaws.com/EXAMPLE_123/abc/123/file.txt
```

Here's an example of the DNS-compliant logic from the official PHP SDK.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/S3/S3Client.php#L293-L317